# How can I pass input to my program while debugging it with IDA

Tags: ida, linux

I have a program that waits for the user to enter a string input, how can I enter that string input while debugging my program with IDA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use I/O redirection operators in the [Process options-Parameters field](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/1398.shtml):

> The standard input/output/error channels can be redirected using the
>   bash shell notations. for example: `>output 2>&1`

Comment: Brilliant !!!! I love IDA :D

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer after hours of searching, it is really sad that such a great tool doesn't have this option easily enabled.
anyway, you have to lunch the IDA from the terminal but you have to add

> "cat |"

before it.
For me, it was like this

```
cat | ./ida64
```

and then when the program waits for the user's input, you have to go back to the terminal and supply it there.

If you want to add a file as an input you can do this

```
cat myfile | ./ida64
```

If you know any better solution please post it here.

Comment: You may as well use `yes` then. If this above method worked you may also want to check out `expect` and its variants (such as `pexpect`).